# Access or Access to

Tags: word-usage

What version is right?
1. I need access to from new email?
2. I need access from new email?
Thank you. I didn’t find answer in another site.

Comment: 'Access to' means the ability to get into a place or to make contact with someone. 'Access from' doesn't make sense. We would never use 'to' and 'from' together. What idea are you trying to express?

Comment: Both are clearly wrong, which suggests you should take the same somewhere such as English Language Learners.

Since you're here, "… access to (new) e-mail" works.

"… access from (new) email" could never work.

In some circumstances, "access from…" would be fine and dandy; e-mail isn't one.

"… access *from* my computer/desktop/laptop/mobile *to* (whatever)" works and how much more specific is that?
 
When you "didn’t find answer in another site" should we guess; could say which site that was or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

access to - this is a noun with a preposition. eg I need access to your emails. (the verb here is need)
to access something - this is a verb and wouldn't take the preposition  eg I accessed your emails yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

### To fix both of your statements:

> • I need access to **___** (e.g. it, that) from **my** new email.
>
> • I need access from **my** new email.